# Two TextInputLayout in the same line

Tags: android, material-design

How to use two `TextInputLayout(Material Design)` in the same line i.e horizontally such that they must acquire all the horizontal space in the Linear Layout equally. I have tried with the linear layout

```
           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/firstname"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:hint="@string/fhint"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:elevation="6dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/lastname"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:hint="@string/lhint"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:elevation="6dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:maxLength="15"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Weight should be set only in your TextInputLayout, remove it from your EditTexts

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/fhint"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/lhint"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```